# Translate my routes without affecting the originals with route_translator gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am using [this gem](https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator) to translate my routes, I am working with two languages in my project, `spanish` and `english`

I translate my routes this way:

```
localized do
  namespace :admin do
    resources :events
  end
end
```

that generates me:

```
/es/admin/events
/en/admin/events
```

I need to add translations in `config/locales/*.yml`

for example in `es.yml`

```
routes:
    admin: administrador
    events: eventos
```

That works fine, but the problem is that I have a `.js` that does `post`, `put` or `get` to specific routes, and that causes me error

```
$http.get('/admin/events/' + id)
```

when translating my route in `.yml` the previous route does not exist

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

What are `RouteTranslator.config.generate_unlocalized_routes` or `RouteTranslator.config.force_locale` set to in your application? If I look at [the documentation for RouteTranslator](https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator#available-configurations), I see those are relevant to your use case.